# BigQuery stops importing data from Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics

My second BigQuery project has stopped importing data from Firebase Analytics. The last import was succeeded 2 weeks ago. But intraday import continue works well. Crashlytics too.

The activity section doesn't contain any relevant information.
All limits and quotas don't reach even half.

I use the sandbox version, and I don't have any notifications that could point to any trouble.

My first project on another (company account) stopped to do import a month ago. I've re-linked it, and now BigQuery shows only a 20% of actual data.

What could be the problem? What part of the rules/limits did I miss?

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hello. No. I've checked everything twice, but still don't have any ideas. I'm going to wait a few weeks and then enable the paid plan just to be able to contact the official support concerning my issue.

Comment: I'm investigating this too. See the link https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity  
 and select the app. It may contain some detail of the issue we are experiencing.

Comment: I found the message "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free storage for projects. For more info, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas" but I don't think I exceeded the quota. I checked using this query "SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes FROM <dataset>.__TABLES__" and my project is using only 1053461 bytes = 1MB. In BQ, I expanded "PROJECT HISTORY" tab, and I found some failed jobs. I selected one job and then "REPEAT LOAD JOB" and after executing it, an event table was created. BQ is considering my project has exceeded its quota, but it hasn't.

Comment: Did you find the message with quota in an activity section?

Comment: Yes, but it appears in "PROJECT HISTORY" tab too. Try filtering by period. In my case this message appears since I started having problems with it. Did you find any messages?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I found the "quota exceeded" message after enabling the "Data Access" check box in filters. Anyway, I can't figure out what limit is exceeded, but it seems to switch to a paid plan will solve the problem.

Comment: Possibly. With the paid plan, we can get feedback from the support team. I've unlinked the export to bigquery in one of my projects and I'm going to wait a month to enable it again, hoping that this limit, whatever it is, will be reset.

Comment: Hi @radya, check my answer! Everything is working here again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that this problem occurs when "OAuth consent screen" is not configured.

After configuring this through the link https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent everything worked again.

It seems this was not a requirement in the past and for this reason my older projects were not getting data from firebase into bigQuery.

The error message shown in BigQuery mentioning the quota limit is completely wrong.

Ignore the error message and perform the screen configuration of "OAuth consent screen" via the above link.

Comment: Hello! We've solved that problem, by switching to a paid plan. It seems "OAuth consent screen" contains options for testing purposes, but we are using our projects in production. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.